# 19r1 generated SQL from BQL Mistake?

Tags: sql, acumatica

Runtime error when try to retrieve the detail records, due to generated select
MIX of PXSelector and PXDBCalc, and inheritance just for fun
When try to pull up an existing record (NOT use the selector), it's failing on the SQL

Not sure how much anyone might help, but wanted to report something regardless...

Seems to be a mismatch of the parameters:
--@P0='INV',**@P1=4899**,@P2=N'USD',**@P3=N'AR005697'**
Taken from SQL Profiler, and bunch of where clauses chopped out.  Key issue is P1 - In sub select it should be P3, right now it's giving me:*Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'AR005747' to data type int.*
Quite a mess of logic, but here is the partial select:

```
SELECT
        *,
        (
                SELECT
                        TOP (1) SUM( [XPMPaymentHdrAssocDoc].[Amount])
                FROM
                        [XPMPaymentHdrAssocDoc] [XPMPaymentHdrAssocDoc]
                INNER JOIN
                        [XPMPaymentHdr] [XPMPaymentHdr]
                ON
                        (
                                [XPMPaymentHdr].[CompanyID] = 2)
                AND     [XPMPaymentHdr].[PaymentID] = [XPMPaymentHdrAssocDoc].[PaymentID]
                WHERE
                        (
                                [XPMPaymentHdrAssocDoc].[CompanyID] = 2)
                AND     (
                                [XPMPaymentHdrAssocDoc].[AssocDocType] = @P0
                        AND     **[XPMPaymentHdrAssocDoc].[AssocDocID]   = @P1**
                        )
        )
FROM
        [ARRegister] [XPMARRegister]
WHERE
        (
                [XPMARRegister].[CompanyID] = 2)
AND     ( (
                        [XPMARRegister].[DocType]    = @P0
                AND     **[XPMARRegister].[CustomerID] = @P1**
                AND     [XPMARRegister].[CuryID]     = @P2)
        AND     (
                        [XPMARRegister].[RefNbr] = @P3))
--@P0='INV',**@P1=4899**,@P2=N'USD',@P3=N'AR005697'
```

How - Great pile of fun...

1. DAC (partial, lots removed for clarity.  PXUnboundDefault worked, but the PXDBScalar fails)
   Worked - Selects fine.  BUT can't use in the PXRestriction of a selector later on....

   [System.SerializableAttribute()]
   [PXHidden]
   public class XPMARRegister : ARRegister
   {
   #region Inherited Fields
   public abstract class docType : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field { }
   public abstract class refNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field { }
   public abstract class curyInfoID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlLong.Field { }
   public abstract class curyDocBal : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field { }
   public abstract class docBal : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field { }
   public abstract class released : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field { }
   public abstract class openDoc : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field { }
   public abstract class hold : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field { }
   #endregion

   ```
    public abstract class xPMPaymentHdrAssocDocUnrelasedPaymentAmount : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }

    //[PXUnboundDefault(typeof(Select5<
    //    XPMPaymentHdrAssocDoc,
    //    InnerJoin<XPMPaymentHdr,
    //        On<XPMPaymentHdr.paymentID, Equal<XPMPaymentHdrAssocDoc.paymentID>>>,
    //    Where<XPMPaymentHdrAssocDoc.assocDocType, Equal<Current<XPMARRegister.docType>>,
    //        And<XPMPaymentHdrAssocDoc.assocDocID, Equal<Current<XPMARRegister.refNbr>>,
    //        And<Where<XPMPaymentHdr.status, Equal<PaymentStatusList.applied>,
    //            Or<XPMPaymentHdr.status, Equal<PaymentStatusList.eligibleforSubmission>,
    //            Or<XPMPaymentHdr.status, Equal<PaymentStatusList.open>,
    //            Or<XPMPaymentHdr.status, Equal<PaymentStatusList.approved>>>>>>>>,
    //    Aggregate<
    //        Sum<XPMPaymentHdrAssocDoc.curyAmount, Sum<XPMPaymentHdrAssocDoc.amount>>>>), SourceField = typeof(XPMPaymentHdrAssocDoc.amount), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXDBScalar(typeof(Search5<
       XPMPaymentHdrAssocDoc.amount,
       InnerJoin<XPMPaymentHdr,
           On<XPMPaymentHdr.paymentID, Equal<XPMPaymentHdrAssocDoc.paymentID>>>,
       Where<XPMPaymentHdrAssocDoc.assocDocType, Equal<Current<XPMARRegister.docType>>,
           And<XPMPaymentHdrAssocDoc.assocDocID, Equal<Current<XPMARRegister.refNbr>>,
           And<Where<XPMPaymentHdr.status, Equal<PaymentStatusList.applied>,
               Or<XPMPaymentHdr.status, Equal<PaymentStatusList.eligibleforSubmission>,
               Or<XPMPaymentHdr.status, Equal<PaymentStatusList.open>,
               Or<XPMPaymentHdr.status, Equal<PaymentStatusList.approved>>>>>>>>,
       Aggregate<Sum<XPMPaymentHdrAssocDoc.amount>>>))]
    [PXDecimal(4)]
    public virtual Decimal? XPMPaymentHdrAssocDocUnrelasedPaymentAmount
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
   ```

   }

Used within 2nd DAC (again, greatly reduced):
ROUGH logic - I want open invoices, with a balance, reduced by my own payment amount
Failing, apparently, due to THIS PXSelector

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[PXPrimaryGraph(typeof(XPARInvoicePayment))]
[PXCacheName(Messages.CacheXPMPayAppDet)]
public class XPMPayAppDetAR : XPMPayAppDet
{
    #region AssocDocModule

    [PXDBString(2, IsFixed = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Document Module")]
    [PXDefault(AssocDocModuleList.AccountReceivableKey)]
    [AssocDocModuleList.List()]
    public override String AssocDocModule { get; set; }

    #endregion AssocDocModule

    #region AssocDocType

    public new abstract class assocDocType : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<assocDocType>
    {
    }

    [PXDBString(3, IsFixed = true)]
    [ARDocType.List()]
    [PXDefault(ARDocType.Invoice)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Associated Document Type")]
    public override String AssocDocType { get; set; }

    #endregion AssocDocType

    #region AssocDocID

    public new abstract class assocDocID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<assocDocID>
    {
    }

    [PXDBString(15, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Document ID")]
    **[PXSelector(typeof(Search<XPMARRegister.refNbr, Where<XPMARRegister.docType, Equal<Current<XPMPayAppDetAR.assocDocType>>, And<XPMARRegister.customerID, Equal<Current<XPMPayAppHdr.customerID>>, And<XPMARRegister.curyID, Equal<Current<XPMPayAppHdr.curyID>>>>>>), DescriptionField = typeof(XPMARRegister.docDesc))]**
    [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<XPMARRegister.hold, Equal<False>>), Messages.DocumentOnHold)]
    [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<XPMARRegister.openDoc, Equal<True>>), Messages.DocumentNotOpen)]
    [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<XPMARRegister.released, Equal<True>>), Messages.DocumentUnreleased)]
    [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<XPMARRegister.docBal, Greater<decimal0>>), Messages.DocumentNotOpen)]
//        [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<XPMARRegister.docBalLessUnrelased, Greater<decimal0>>), Messages.DocumentNotOpen)]
[PXCheckUnique(typeof(XPMPayAppDetAR.xPAppID), typeof(XPMPayAppDetAR.assocDocModule), typeof(XPMPayAppDetAR.assocDocType), typeof(XPMPayAppDetAR.assocDocID), IgnoreNulls = false, ClearOnDuplicate = true)]
    public override String AssocDocID { get; set; }

    #endregion AssocDocID

}
```

Graph, not that it's very interesting (again, highly reduced):

```
public class XPARInvoicePayment : PXGraph<XPARInvoicePayment, XPMPayAppHdr>
{
    public ToggleCurrency<XPMPayAppHdr> CurrencyView;
    public PXSelect<XPMPayAppHdr> Document;
    public PXSelect<XPMPayAppDet, Where<XPMPayAppDet.xPAppID, Equal<Current<XPMPayAppHdr.xPAppID>>>> DetailsAll;
    **public PXSelect<XPMPayAppDetAR, Where<XPMPayAppDetAR.xPAppID, Equal<Current<XPMPayAppHdr.xPAppID>>, And<XPMPayAppDetSO.assocDocModule, Equal<AssocDocModuleList.accountReceivable>>>> DetailsAR;**
    public PXSelect<XPMPayAppDetSO, Where<XPMPayAppDetSO.xPAppID, Equal<Current<XPMPayAppHdr.xPAppID>>, And<XPMPayAppDetSO.assocDocModule, Equal<AssocDocModuleList.salesOrder>>>> DetailsSO;

    public PXSetup<XPMSetup> PaymentSetup;
}
```

Comment: I noticed that you are using "Current" on your PXDBScalar bql query, that can be an issue.
Please note the following when working with PXDBScalar attribute:

-It only works with tables DAC, table fields. So DACs used and fields used with PXDBScalar have to exist on the Database. 

-Current does not work with PXDBScalar. Try to remove those current(s) statements. If that XPMPaymentHdrAssocDocUnrelasedPaymentAmount field is being defined on the XPMARRegister DAC. Then use XPMARRegister.docType instead of Current<XPMARRegister.docType> for example.

Comment: Well, changing the attribute did it...  VERY good session by Mr. Kralko on "Understanding & Using Acumatica Attributes", current link https://www.acumatica.com/acumatica-virtual-developer-conference/.  Particular recording https://www.youtube.com/embed/BpA6hQ3WeTs?feature=oembed, and slide deck https://www.acumatica.com/media/2021/03/2021-Virtual-DevCon-Attribues.pdf.  He explicitly went over several of the "Do's and Don'ts", and where each attribute is executed